# How to change the QGIS help dialog?

Tags: python, qgis, plugins

I am working with python plugins for QGIS. I am done with my one of my .py file using python 2.5 and pyqt4. It is just help file for QGIS, which i changed. I wanted to incorporate the same in QGIS. I installed QGIS 1.7.1. I know it to be done through python plugins. But how to go about it? where to copy my file, so that it will get open from QGIS? QGIS already has that page (help file ), I need to change it. Help me out.

Comment: What page are you trying to change?

Comment: Help page RT SQL query builder of QGIS...